# Can't get my tic-tac-toe board to recognize winner with images replacing text "X" and "O"

Tags: jquery, image, tic-tac-toe

Here's my current code, which I recently made updates to swap out "X"s and "O"s for my player markers with images instead. In doing so, I'm having trouble keeping my getWinner function to continue working. I've tried a number of things but to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var turn = 0;

  function checkWin() {
     if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box2').html()===icon &&     $('#box3').html()===icon ) {
       $('#box1, #box2, #box3');
       alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box4').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box6').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box4, #box5, #box6');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box7').html()===icon && $('#box8').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box7, #box8, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box4').html()===icon && $('#box7').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box1, #box4, #box7');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box2').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box8').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box2, #box5, #box8');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box3').html()===icon && $('#box6').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box3, #box6, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box3').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box7').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box3, #box5, #box7');
      alert(player + ' won!');
     } else if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box1, #box5, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');

     } else if (turn === 9) {
      alert("It's a draw!");
    }
  }

  $(".box").click(function handleTurn(event){
    if ( !$(this).html() ) {
      turn ++;

      if (turn % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).html("Vader");
        icon = $('<img id="vader" src="darthvader.png" />');
        player = "Vader";
      }

      else if (turn % 2 !== 0) {
        $(this).html("Luke");
        icon = $('<img id="luke" src="lukeskywalker.png" />');
        player = "Luke";
      }
      $(this).html(icon);
      checkWin();
    }
  });

  $(".btn").click(function resetBoard(event) {
    $(".box").empty();
    turn = 0;
  });

});
```

---

Before I messed around with this and replaced text with images, I was able to get the board to recognize the winners, here's V1 with just text:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var turn = 0;

  function checkWin() {
    if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box2').html()===icon && $('#box3').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box1, #box2, #box3');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box4').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box6').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box4, #box5, #box6');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box7').html()===icon && $('#box8').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box7, #box8, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box4').html()===icon && $('#box7').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box1, #box4, #box7');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box2').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box8').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box2, #box5, #box8');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box3').html()===icon && $('#box6').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box3, #box6, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box3').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box7').html()===icon ) {
     $('#box3, #box5, #box7');
      alert(player + ' won!');
    } else if ( $('#box1').html()===icon && $('#box5').html()===icon && $('#box9').html()===icon ) {
      $('#box1, #box5, #box9');
      alert(player + ' won!');

    } else if (turn === 9) {
      alert("It's a draw!");
    }
  }

  $(".box").click(function handleTurn(event){
    if ( !$(this).text() ) {
      turn ++;

      if (turn % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).html("O");
        icon = "O";
        player = "Player O";
      }

      else if (turn % 2 !== 0) {
        $(this).text("X");
        icon = "X";
        player = "Player X";
      }
      $(this).html(icon);
      checkWin();
    }
  });

  $(".btn").click(function resetBoard(event) {
    $(".box").empty();
    turn = 0;
  });
```

---

Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating jQuery DOM elements with your

```
 icon = $('<img id="luke" src="lukeskywalker.png" />');
```

line, whereas you previously set the html to plain text.
Therefore you should no longer compare the .html() of your ('#box#')es with the icon but rather with the icon.html()

Comment: Hmmm, so I tried changing my checkWin function with your suggestion for the first winning combination, however, it didn't do anything:

    function checkWin() {
      if ( icon.html()===icon && icon.html()===icon && icon.html()===icon ) {
         $('#box1, #box2, #box3');
         alert(player + ' won!');

Comment: You are currently comparing the icon with its innerHTML. What I meant was comparing the icon html with the box html like so:
checkWin() { if ( $('#box1').html()===icon.html() && $('#box2').html()===icon.html() && $('#box3').html()===icon.html() ) { $('#box1, #box2, #box3'); alert(player + ' won!');

Comment: Though it would be easier and much cleaner to set an attribute:
$(this).attr('player', player);
as an addition to $(this).html(icon);
and check the $('#box1').attr('player') == player